# code igniter query where condition is different to equals

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Hy guys I need to realize a query in codigniter in which the condition is greater than. 
I have a table named "magazzino" in which there are 2 columns : "quantita" and "alert" I wuold realize query as: 
`SELECT * FROM magazzino WHERE(quantità>alerts)`
I tried in this way:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('magazzino');
$this->db->where('quantita>', 'alerts');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

But this doesn't work. 
Thanks in advance to all for your patience but they're novice with this framework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this example from the Codeigniter documentation:

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);
$this->db->where('id <', $id); 

// Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' AND id < 45
```

It looks as though you may need a space between quantita and >. Try:

```
$this->db->where('quantita >', 'alerts');
```

Comment: damn space!! I HAVE SEEN THE DOCUMENTATION BUT HAD NOT NOTICED THE SPACE! however it works! Thanks